# XCOPY not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am very new to batch file coding. I am trying to use XCOPY for copying some file. First I used like this:

```
@echo off

MOVE mypath\abc.txt mypath\abc.txt.0001
XCOPY mypath\abc.txt.bak mypath\abc.txt

pause
```

This code is working perfectly fine.
Then I needed to take some input from user, o I modified the code like this:

```
@ECHO off

ECHO Starting application.
SET /p path=Enter the path: 
SET /p corruptFileName=Enter the corrupted file name: 
SET /p oldBackupFileName=Enter the Backup file name to restore: 
SET /p correuptedBackupName=Enter the corrupted backup file name: 

ECHO Path : 
ECHO %path%
ECHO Corrupted file name : 
ECHO %corruptFileName%
ECHO Desired Backup file name:
ECHO %correuptedBackupName%
ECHO Backup file name to restore : 
ECHO %oldBackupFileName%


MOVE %path%\%corruptFileName% %path%\%correuptedBackupName%
call :waitfor 5000>nul
XCOPY %path%\%oldBackupFileName% %path%\%corruptFileName%

PAUSE
```

This code is not running. It says that :

```
The system cannot find the batch label specified - waitfor
'XCOPY' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can anyone shed any light in this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%path%` is an environment variable that is used to tell the operating system where programs are located. Without it, you have to give the full path to system executables (like `xcopy`) before they can be called by name only.

**Never overwrite it.**

Change the variable name to something else. Anything else.

Comment: @JavaProgrammer - Happy to help. Since my answer worked for you, please click the check mark next to my answer.

Comment: Done!! Accepted as answer :)